# Simplifying an SQL statement -- Many to many relationship

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a generic problem when selecting records from a table with many-many relationships
suppose as an example I have the two tables as follows:

```
 MainTable:
  id <-- Primary key
  description

 DataTable:
  id <-- Primary key
  data1
  data2
  data3
  description FOREIGN KEY of Table(MainTable)
```

I currently have the following query:

> myelements = executeSQL(select distinct description from MainTable order by description)

and then I use the elements obtained from this query to perform yet another query:

```
for item in myelements:
    executeSQL(select data1 from DataTable where description = item)
```

Is there a way to remove this for loop and have a single sql statement to perform this operation?

I would like to bundle up all records from the DataTable for all of the available descriptions and
store them in code.
so that I have something as:

> `map[description] = every row of that description in DataTable`

Comment: `select data1 from DataTable JOIN MainTable ON DataTable.description=MainTable.description where DataTable.description=item`

Comment: Not related to your question, but your database design could be better.  Specifically, drop the description field in your datatable, and replace it with MainTableID.  This will be your foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `join` like this :

```
SELECT MT.description, group_concat(DT.data1) 
FROM DataTable DT JOIN MainTable MT ON (DT.description = MT.description)
GROUP BY MT.description
ORDER BY MT.description
```

Comment: Yes, that is much closer to what I want, the only problem I have is that the values get returned as for examples: (description1 | data1),(description1| data2), (description1| data3). 
Is there a way to concatenate them so that I get something like, (description1 | data1,data2,data3,data4 ...), (description2 | data1,data2,data3,...)

I am using the sql in a program where I would have to iterate through all of the returned values and as in the query above that would be alot of values which decreases the value of the database.

Comment: Wow!! never knew something like that existed. Yes thats exactly what I wanted :) thanks alot